# Hive JOIN of query with subquery takes forever

Tags: hadoop, hive

Lately I have been playing a bit with Hive. Most things have been progressing well, however, when I try to convert something like

```
2015-04-01   device1   traffic    other       start   
2015-04-01   device1   traffic    violation   deny 
2015-04-01   device1   traffic    violation   deny 
2015-04-02   device1   traffic    other       start   
2015-04-03   device1   traffic    other       start   
2015-04-03   device1   traffic    other       start
```

Into

```
2015-04-01   1       2
2015-04-02   1       
2015-04-03   2
```

I tried using the following query but for some reason the reduce stage of the query just gets stuck at 96% no matter how long I wait.

```
SELECT pass.date, COUNT(pass.type), COUNT(deny.deny_type) FROM firewall_logs as pass
JOIN (
SELECT date, type as deny_type FROM firewall_logs
WHERE device = 'device1' 
AND date LIKE '2015-04-%'
AND type = 'traffic' AND subtype = 'violation' and status = 'deny' 
) deny ON ( pass.date = deny.date  )
WHERE pass.device = 'device1' 
AND pass.date LIKE '2015-04-%'
AND pass.type = 'traffic' AND pass.subtype = 'other' AND pass.status = 'start'
GROUP BY pass.date ORDER BY pass.date ;
```

All MR2 logs show is:

```
2015-06-11 01:54:04,206 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator: table 0 has 9028000 rows for join key [2015-04-26]
2015-06-11 01:54:04,423 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator: table 0 has 9128000 rows for join key [2015-04-26]
2015-06-11 01:54:04,638 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator: table 0 has 9228000 rows for join key [2015-04-26]
2015-06-11 01:54:04,838 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
```

Would anyone have an idea of why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid self-joins in Hive like the plague.  You can do this by collecting and creating a map

```
add jar ./brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select date
  , c_map['start'] starts
  , c_map['deny'] denies
from (
  select date
    , collect(status, c) c_map
  from (
    select date, status
      , count( subtype ) c
    from table
    where device='device1' and type='traffic'
    group by date, status ) x
  group by date ) y
```